# Access a stringed variable based on a drop down and text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to access a certain "pipe" based on a drop down and text box. The way I have set it up is that the value of the drop down can match the string in `var automobiles` then somehow it would need to know how to access the correct weight based on what the user enters in the textbox. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Can someone please help?

http://jsfiddle.net/wb9z2uuw/1/

** Maybe something like `var exampleWeightClass = Automobiles["2D"].vehicleClass;` ???? How would it know to fall into the correct `vehicleClass`?

```js
var Automobiles = {

    "2D": [{
        vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],

    "3D": [{
        vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody">
<option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="2D">2-Door Coupe</option>
    <option value="3D">3-Door Hatchback</option>
</select>

<label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
         <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew">
```

Comment: What behavior are you looking for once user inputs the weight?

Comment: As of right now I want to just make sure there accessing the correct pipes maybe seeing that in the console log? Like if 2D is chosen from the dropdown and the weight entered is in between 2500 to 3499 that it grabs the correct pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's how I would do it.  First, in your objects, I would assign a minWeight and maxWeight numeric property so it can be checked in the loop.

```
var Automobiles = {
    "2D": [{
        vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
        minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
        minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
        minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],

    "3D": [{
        vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
        minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
        minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
        minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }]
};
```

Now, I assign a change event handler (I'm using jQuery, but you could use plain javascript if you like - I saw jQuery in the tag so I opted to use it here).

In the event handler, loop through the automobiles object to find the value that's selected in the dropdown.  Then loop through the array of objects within that category to see if the weight entered is between the minWeight and maxWeight values that are assigned for that object.  If they are, then return the pipe value for that object (which I'm just throwing an alert for an example)

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wb9z2uuw/2/

```
$("#ew, vehiclebody").change(function () {
    if ($("#ew").val() !== "" && $("#vehiclebody :selected").val() !== "") {
        for (var i in Automobiles) {
            if (i === $("#vehiclebody :selected").val()) {
                for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                    if ($("#ew").val() >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && $("#ew").val() < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                        alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Pure JavaScript example as requested:   http://jsfiddle.net/wb9z2uuw/4/

```
var ew = document.getElementById("ew");
var vehiclebody = document.getElementById("vehiclebody");
var eventHandler = function () {
    if (ew.value !== "" && vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value != "") {
        for (var i in Automobiles) {
            if (i === vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value) {
                for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                    if (ew.value >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && ew.value < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                        alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                        break;
                    }                        
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
ew.addEventListener("change", function () { eventHandler(); });
vehiclebody.addEventListener("change", function () { eventHandler(); });
```

Comment: Any chance you can show me how to do that in just JavaScript too? I am interested in both ways :)

Comment: I've added a pure JavaScript example to the answer :)

Comment: Any chance I can pick you brain a little further? :)

Comment: Anytime...  FYI - my brain is going to check-out for the day in about 45 minutes so if I don't get to it today, I definitely will tomorrow.

Comment: Depending on different options that are chosen it needs to pick from the drop down and the correct corresponding textbox I am trying to combine the function I wrote and put at the top of the fiddle with yours

Comment: why not just change the label text depending on what is selected?  It doesn't appear that you would need 3 separate text boxes, just one textbox and just change the label depending on data you need from the end user.

Comment: Only problem with that is the ones that have gvw , ew still needs to also show

Comment: I was going to do something like a show hide div I think depending on the choice selected and none if it doesn't need that box to calculate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64900/discussion-between-howard-renollet-and-vicki).