# Access a stringed variable based on a drop down and a specific text box depending on the choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to access a certain "pipe" based on a drop down and text box. The trick here is that certain options from the drop down are going to either require the ew(empty weight) or gvw(gross vehicle weight) or ft(feet) or none. The way I have set it up is that the value of the drop down can match the string in var automobiles then somehow it would need to know how to access the correct weight based on what the user enters in the correct corresponding textbox. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Can someone please help?

http://jsfiddle.net/wb9z2uuw/7/

** Maybe something like var exampleWeightClass = Automobiles["2D"].vehicleClass; ???? How would it know to fall into the correct vehicleClass and know which textbox it is coming from?

```js
function getWeight(vehicle) { 
 if(vehicle == '2D' || vehicle == '3D' || vehicle == '4D' || vehicle == '5D' || vehicle == 'CV' || vehicle == 'UT' || vehicle == 'SW' || vehicle == 'TL1' || vehicle == 'TL2' || vehicle == 'PK' || vehicle == 'VN1' || vehicle == 'VN3' || vehicle == 'CA2' ||vehicle == 'PC' || vehicle == 'MH' ) { 
 return $('#ew').val();  //WEIGHT BASED ON EW
 } 
 else if(vehicle == 'TK1' || vehicle == 'TK2' || vehicle == 'TK3' || vehicle == 'TK4' || vehicle == 'TK5' ||  vehicle == 'VN2' ) { 
 return $('#gvw').val(); //WEIGHT BASED ON GVW 
 } 
 else if(vehicle == 'HS1' || vehicle == 'HS2' || vehicle == 'TV1' || vehicle == 'TV2' ) { 
 return $('#ft').val(); //WEIGHT BASED ON FT 
 } 
 else { 
 return 0; //CA1, HS3, PT1, PT2, MC1, MC2, MP
 }
}    

var Automobiles = {

    "2D": [{
        vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
  minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
  minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],

        
 "UT": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
  minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
  minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],
 
 "SW": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
  minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
  minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],
 
 "TL1": [{ 
  vehicleClass: "0 to 500",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 501, 
  pipe: [6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 2, 18.35, 6.75, 1, 1, 52, 52] 
 }],
 
 "TL2": [{
  vehicleClass: "501 and up",
  minWeight: 501,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
  pipe: [t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t, 1, t12, pt, 2, 2, 53, 53] 
 }],
 
 "PK": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 1999",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2000, 
  pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "2000 to 3000",
  minWeight: 2000,
        maxWeight: 3001, 
  pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "3001 to 5000",
  minWeight: 3001,
        maxWeight: 5001, 
  pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }],
     
 "TK1": [{//pipe r22 has both 41 & 410
  vehicleClass: "5001 to 5999",
  minWeight: 5001,
        maxWeight: 6000,  
  pipe: [5.06, 10.13, 15.19, 20.25, 25.31, 30.38, 35.44, 40.50, 45.56, 50.63, 55.69, 60.75, 65.81, 70.88, 75.94, 1, 72.35, 60.75, 2, 3, 0, 41] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "6000 to 7999",
  minWeight: 6000,
        maxWeight: 8000,
  pipe: [7.31, 14.63, 21.94, 29.25, 36.56, 43.88, 51.19, 58.50, 65.81, 73.13, 80.44, 87.75, 95.06, 102.38, 109.69, 1, 99.35, 87.75, 2, 3, 0, 41] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "8000 to 9999",
  minWeight: 8000,
        maxWeight: 10000,
  pipe: [8.58, 17.17, 25.75, 34.33, 42.92, 51.50, 60.08, 68.67, 77.25, 85.83, 94.92, 103.00, 111.58, 120.17, 128.75, 1, 2, 103.00, 2, 1, 0, 41] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "10,000 to 14,999", 
  minWeight: 10000,
        maxWeight: 15000,
  pipe: [9.83, 19.67, 29.50, 39.33, 49.17, 59.00, 68.83, 78.67, 88.50, 98.33, 108.17, 118.00, 127.83, 137.67, 147.50, 1, 2, 118.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "15,000 to 19,999",
  minWeight: 15000,
        maxWeight: 20000,
  pipe: [14.75, 29.50, 44.25, 59.00, 73.75, 88.50, 103.25, 118.00, 132.75, 147.50, 162.25, 177.00, 191.75, 206.50, 221.25, 1, 2, 177.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "20,000 to 26,000",
  minWeight: 20000,
        maxWeight: 26001,
  pipe: [20.92, 41.83, 62.75, 83.67, 104.58, 125.50, 146.42, 167.33, 188.25, 209.17, 230.08, 251.00, 271.92, 292.83, 313.75, 1, 2, 251.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "26,001 to 34,999",
  minWeight: 26001,
        maxWeight: 35000,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "35,000 to 43,999", 
  minWeight: 35000,
        maxWeight: 44000,
  pipe: [33.75, 67.50, 101.25, 135.00, 168.75, 202.50, 236.25, 270.00, 303.75, 337.50, 371.25, 405.00, 438.75, 472.50, 506.25, 1, 2, 405.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "44,000 to 54,999", 
  minWeight: 44000,
        maxWeight: 55000,
  pipe: [64.42, 128.83, 193.25, 257.67, 322.08, 386.50, 450.92, 515.33, 579.75, 644.17, 708.58, 773.00, 837.42, 901.83, 966.25, 1, 2, 773.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "55,000 to 61,999", 
  minWeight: 55000,
        maxWeight: 62000,
  pipe: [76.33, 152.67, 229.00, 305.33, 381.67, 458.00, 534.33, 610.67, 687.00, 763.33, 839.67, 916.00, 992.33, 1068.67, 1145.00, 1, 2, 916.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "62,000 to 71,999", 
  minWeight: 62000,
        maxWeight: 72000,
  pipe: [90.00, 180.00, 270.00, 360.00, 450.00, 540.00, 630.00, 720.00, 810.00, 900.00, 990.00, 1080.00, 1170.00, 1260.00, 1350.00, 1, 2, 1080.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "72,000 to 80,000", 
  minWeight: 72000,
        maxWeight: 80001,
  pipe: [110.17, 220.33, 330.50, 440.67, 550.83, 661.00, 771.17, 881.33, 991.50, 1101.67, 1211.83, 1322.00, 1432.17, 1542.33, 1652.50, 1, 2, 1322.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }],
     
 "TK2": [{ 
  vehicleClass: "0 to 9999", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 10000,
  pipe: [7.31, 14.63, 21.94, 29.25, 36.56, 43.88, 51.19, 58.50, 65.81, 73.13, 80.44, 87.75, 95.06, 102.38, 109.69, 1, 2, 87.75, 2, 2, 0, 102] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "10,000 thru 43,999", 
  minWeight: 10000,
        maxWeight: 44000,
  pipe: [7.31, 14.63, 21.94, 29.25, 36.56, 43.88, 51.19, 58.50, 65.81, 73.13, 80.44, 87.75, 95.06, 102.38, 109.69, 1, 2, 87.75, 2, 2, 0, 1020] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "44000 to 80,000", 
  minWeight: 44000,
        maxWeight: 80001,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 1020] 
 }],
 
 "TK3": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.63, 6.25, 6.88, 7.50, 8.13, 8.75, 9.38, 1, 2, 7.50, 2, 2, 0, 93] 
 }],
 
 "TK4": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 9999", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 10000,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 39] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "10,000 and up", 
  minWeight: 10000,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 390] 
 }],
 
 "TK5": [{
  vehicleClass: "10,000 to 14,999", 
  minWeight: 10000,
        maxWeight: 15000,
  pipe: [9.83, 19.67, 29.50, 39.33, 49.17, 59.00, 68.83, 78.67, 88.50, 98.33, 108.17, 118.00, 127.83, 137.67, 147.50, 1, 2, 118.00, 2, 2, 0, 410]
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "15,000 to 19,999", 
  minWeight: 15000,
        maxWeight: 20000,
  pipe: [14.75, 29.50, 44.25, 59.00, 73.75, 88.50, 103.25, 118.00, 132.75, 147.50, 162.25, 177.00, 191.75, 206.50, 221.25, 1, 2, 177.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "20,000 to 25,999", 
  minWeight: 20000,
        maxWeight: 26000,
  pipe: [20.92, 41.83, 62.75, 83.67, 104.58, 125.50, 146.42, 167.33, 188.25, 209.17, 230.08, 251.00, 271.92, 292.83, 313.75, 1, 2, 251.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "26,000 to 34,999", 
  minWeight: 26000,
        maxWeight: 35000,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "35,000 to 43,999", 
  minWeight: 35000,
        maxWeight: 44000,
  pipe: [33.75, 67.50, 101.25, 135.00, 168.75, 202.50, 236.25, 270.00, 303.75, 337.50, 371.25, 405.00, 438.75, 472.50, 506.25, 1, 2, 405.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "44,000 to 54,999", 
  minWeight: 44000,
        maxWeight: 55000,
  pipe: [64.33, 128.67, 193.00, 257.33, 321.67, 386.00, 450.33, 514.67, 579.00, 643.33, 707.67, 772.00, 836.33, 900.67, 965.00, 1, 2, 772.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "55,000 to 61,999", 
  minWeight: 55000,
        maxWeight: 62000,
  pipe: [76.25, 152.50, 228.75, 305.00, 381.25, 457.50, 533.75, 610.00, 686.25, 762.50, 838.75, 915.00, 991.25, 1067.50, 1143.75, 1, 2, 915.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "62,000 to 71,999", 
  minWeight: 62000,
        maxWeight: 72000,
  pipe: [90.00, 180.00, 270.00, 360.00, 450.00, 540.00, 630.00, 720.00, 810.00, 900.00, 990.00, 1080.00, 1170.00, 1260.00, 1350.00, 1, 2, 1080.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "72,000 to 80,000", 
  minWeight: 72000,
        maxWeight: 80001,
  pipe: [110.17, 220.33, 330.50, 440.67, 550.83, 661.00, 771.17, 881.33, 991.50, 1101.67, 1211.83, 1322.00, 1432.17, 1542.33, 1652.50, 1, 2, 1322.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }],
 
 "VN1": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 1999", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2000,
  pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "2000 to 3000", 
  minWeight: 2000,
        maxWeight: 3001,
  pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "3001 to 5000",
  minWeight: 3001,
        maxWeight: 5001,
  pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01] 
 }],
 
 "VN2": [{//pipe r22 has both 41 & 410
  vehicleClass: "5001 to 5999",
  minWeight: 5001,
        maxWeight: 6000,  
  pipe: [5.06, 10.13, 15.19, 20.25, 25.31, 30.38, 35.44, 40.50, 45.56, 50.63, 55.69, 60.75, 65.81, 70.88, 75.94, 1, 72.35, 60.75, 2, 3, 0, 41] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "6000 to 7999",
  minWeight: 6000,
        maxWeight: 8000,
  pipe: [7.31, 14.63, 21.94, 29.25, 36.56, 43.88, 51.19, 58.50, 65.81, 73.13, 80.44, 87.75, 95.06, 102.38, 109.69, 1, 99.35, 87.75, 2, 3, 0, 41] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "8000 to 9999",
  minWeight: 8000,
        maxWeight: 10000,
  pipe: [8.58, 17.17, 25.75, 34.33, 42.92, 51.50, 60.08, 68.67, 77.25, 85.83, 94.92, 103.00, 111.58, 120.17, 128.75, 1, 2, 103.00, 2, 1, 0, 41] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "10,000 to 14,999", 
  minWeight: 10000,
        maxWeight: 15000,
  pipe: [9.83, 19.67, 29.50, 39.33, 49.17, 59.00, 68.83, 78.67, 88.50, 98.33, 108.17, 118.00, 127.83, 137.67, 147.50, 1, 2, 118.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "15,000 to 19,999",
  minWeight: 15000,
        maxWeight: 20000,
  pipe: [14.75, 29.50, 44.25, 59.00, 73.75, 88.50, 103.25, 118.00, 132.75, 147.50, 162.25, 177.00, 191.75, 206.50, 221.25, 1, 2, 177.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "20,000 to 26,000",
  minWeight: 20000,
        maxWeight: 26001,
  pipe: [20.92, 41.83, 62.75, 83.67, 104.58, 125.50, 146.42, 167.33, 188.25, 209.17, 230.08, 251.00, 271.92, 292.83, 313.75, 1, 2, 251.00, 2, 1, 0, 410] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "26,001 to 34,999",
  minWeight: 26001,
        maxWeight: 35000,
  pipe: [27.00, 54.00, 81.00, 108.00, 135.00, 162.00, 189.00, 216.00, 243.00, 270.00, 297.00, 324.00, 351.00, 378.00, 405.00, 1, 2, 324.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "35,000 to 43,999", 
  minWeight: 35000,
        maxWeight: 44000,
  pipe: [33.75, 67.50, 101.25, 135.00, 168.75, 202.50, 236.25, 270.00, 303.75, 337.50, 371.25, 405.00, 438.75, 472.50, 506.25, 1, 2, 405.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "44,000 to 54,999", 
  minWeight: 44000,
        maxWeight: 55000,
  pipe: [64.42, 128.83, 193.25, 257.67, 322.08, 386.50, 450.92, 515.33, 579.75, 644.17, 708.58, 773.00, 837.42, 901.83, 966.25, 1, 2, 773.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "55,000 to 61,999", 
  minWeight: 55000,
        maxWeight: 62000,
  pipe: [76.33, 152.67, 229.00, 305.33, 381.67, 458.00, 534.33, 610.67, 687.00, 763.33, 839.67, 916.00, 992.33, 1068.67, 1145.00, 1, 2, 916.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "62,000 to 71,999", 
  minWeight: 62000,
        maxWeight: 72000,
  pipe: [90.00, 180.00, 270.00, 360.00, 450.00, 540.00, 630.00, 720.00, 810.00, 900.00, 990.00, 1080.00, 1170.00, 1260.00, 1350.00, 1, 2, 1080.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "72,000 to 80,000", 
  minWeight: 72000,
        maxWeight: 80001,
  pipe: [110.17, 220.33, 330.50, 440.67, 550.83, 661.00, 771.17, 881.33, 991.50, 1101.67, 1211.83, 1322.00, 1432.17, 1542.33, 1652.50, 1, 2, 1322.00, 2, 2, 0, 410] 
 }],
  
 
 "VN3": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 2499",
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 2500,
        pipe: [14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 14.50, 29.00, 29.00, 29.00, 1, 27.60, 14.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "2500 to 3499",
  minWeight: 2500,
        maxWeight: 3500,
        pipe: [22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 1, 35.60, 22.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }, {
        vehicleClass: "3500 and up",
  minWeight: 3500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
        pipe: [32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 32.50, 65.00, 65.00, 65.00, 1, 45.60, 32.50, 1, 3, 01, 01]
    }],
 
 "CA1": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 13.50, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 1, 25.10, 13.50, 2, 3, 62, 62] 
 }],
 
 "CA2": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 4499", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 4500,
  pipe: [27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 54.00, 54.00, 54.00, 1, 38.60, 27.00, 1, 3, 42, 42] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "4500 and up", 
  minWeight: 4500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 94.50, 94.50, 94.50, 1, 58.85, 47.25, 1, 3, 42, 42] 
 }],
   
 "HS1": [{//OUTSIDE
  vehicleClass: "0 to 35", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 36,
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 4, 25.10, 20.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "36 to 40", 
  minWeight: 36,
        maxWeight: 41,
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 30.25, 4, 31.10, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "41 to 45", 
  minWeight: 41,
        maxWeight: 46,
  pipe: [7.50, 7.50, 7.50, 15.00, 15.00, 15.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 37.50, 37.50, 37.50, 4, 35.10, 30.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "46 to 50", 
  minWeight: 46,
        maxWeight: 51,
  pipe: [8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 17.50, 17.50, 17.50, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 43.75, 43.75, 43.75, 4, 40.10, 35.00, 2, 2, 0, 51]
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "51 to 55", 
  minWeight: 51,
        maxWeight: 56,
  pipe: [10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 4, 45.10, 40.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "56 to 60", 
  minWeight: 56,
        maxWeight: 61,
  pipe: [11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 56.25, 56.25, 56.25, 4, 50.10, 45.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "61 to 65", 
  minWeight: 61,
        maxWeight: 66,
  pipe: [12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 62.50, 62.50, 62.50, 4, 55.10, 50.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "66 and up", 
  minWeight: 66,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 4, 85.10, 80.00, 2, 2, 0, 51] 
 }],
 
     
 "HS2": [{//INSIDE
  vehicleClass: "0 to 35", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 36,
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 4, 26.10, 20.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "36 to 40", 
  minWeight: 36,
        maxWeight: 41,
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 4, 31.10, 25.00, 2, 2, 1, 510]
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "41 to 45", 
  minWeight: 41,
        maxWeight: 46,
  pipe: [7.50, 7.50, 7.50, 15.00, 15.00, 15.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 30.00, 37.50, 37.50, 37.50, 4, 36.10, 30.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "46 to 50", 
  minWeight: 46,
        maxWeight: 51,
  pipe: [8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 17.50, 17.50, 17.50, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 35.00, 43.75, 43.75, 43.75, 4, 41.10, 35.00, 2, 2, 1, 510]
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "51 to 55", 
  minWeight: 51,
        maxWeight: 56,
  pipe: [10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 4, 46.10, 40.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "56 to 60", 
  minWeight: 56,
        maxWeight: 61,
  pipe: [11.25, 11.25, 11.25, 22.50, 22.50, 22.50, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 45.00, 56.25, 56.25, 56.25, 4, 51.10, 45.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }, {
  vehicleClass: "61 to 65", 
  minWeight: 61,
        maxWeight: 66,
  pipe: [12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 50.00, 62.50, 62.50, 62.50, 4, 56.10, 50.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "66 and up", 
  minWeight: 66,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [20.00, 20.00, 20.00, 40.00, 40.00, 40.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 80.00, 100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 4, 86.10, 80.00, 2, 2, 1, 510] 
 }],
 
 "HS3": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 86] 
 }],   

 "PC": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 4499", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 4500,
  pipe: [27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 54.00, 54.00, 54.00, 1, 38.60, 27.00, 2, 3, 42, 42] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "4500 and up", 
  minWeight: 4500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 94.50, 94.50, 94.50, 1, 58.85, 47.25, 2, 3, 42, 42] 
 }],
 
 "MH": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 4499", 
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 4500,
  pipe: [27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 27.00, 54.00, 54.00, 54.00, 1, 38.60, 27.00, 1, 3, 42, 42] 
 }, { 
  vehicleClass: "4500 and up", 
  minWeight: 4500,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 47.25, 94.50, 94.50, 94.50, 1, 58.85, 47.25, 1, 3, 42, 42]
 }],

 "PT1": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 1, 36.60, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 76] 
 }],
 
 "PT2": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 1, 36.60, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 76] 
 }],
 
 "TV1": [{
  vehicleClass: "0 to 35", //ft
  minWeight: 0,
        maxWeight: 36,
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 1, 36.60, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 76] 
 }],

 "TV2": [{
  vehicleClass: "36 and up", //ft
  minWeight: 36,
        maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 1, 36.60, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 78] 
 }],

 "MC1": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 1, 24.10, 10.00, 2, 1, 65, 65] 
 }],
 
 "MC2": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 10.00, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 1, 24.10, 10.00, 2, 1, 65, 65] 
 }],
 
 "MP": [{
  vehicleClass: "none", 
  pipe: [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 2, 19.10, 6.75, 2, 1, 69, 69] 
 }]
 };

   var weight = getWeight(vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value);
    var vehiclebody = document.getElementById("vehiclebody");
    var eventHandler = function () {
        if (weight !== "" && vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value != "") {
            for (var i in Automobiles) {
                if (i === vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value) {
                    for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                        if (weight >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && weight < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                            alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody">
<option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="2D">2-Door Coupe</option>
    <option value="UT">Sport Utility Vehicle</option>
    <option value="SW">Station Wagon</option>
    <option value="TL1">Trailers (utility or boat) under 500 lbs</option>
    <option value="TL2">Trailers (utility or boat) over 500 lbs</option>
 <option value="PK">Truck (Equal to or Less than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="TK1">Truck (More than 5000 lbs)</option>
 <option value="TK2">Agricultural Truck</option>
 <option value="TK3">Agricultural Goat</option>
 <option value="TK4">Forestry Truck</option>
 <option value="TK5">Wrecker Truck</option>
    <option value="VN1">Van-Cargo (Equal to or Less than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="VN2">Van-Cargo (More than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="VN3">Van-Passenger</option>
    <option value="CA1">Camper (folding wall or popup)</option>
 <option value="CA2">Chassis Mount Camper (unit affixed to truck chassis)</option>
    <option value="HS1">Mobile Home Outside Mobile Home Park(rental property)</option>
 <option value="HS2">Mobile Home Inside Mobile Home Park(rental property)</option>
    <option value="HS3">Mobile Home (real property)</option>
    <option value="PC">Motor Coach (3 axles)</option>
    <option value="MH">Motor Home (2 axles)</option>
    <option value="PT1">Park Model (rental property)</option>
    <option value="PT2">Park Model (real property)</option>
    <option value="TV1">Travel Trailer</option>
    <option value="TV2">Travel Trailer (real property)</option>
    <option value="MC1">Motorcycle (More than 2bhp or 50cc)</option>
    <option value="MC2">Motorscooter (Equal to/Less than 2bhp/50cc)</option>
    <option value="MP">Moped (Equal to/Less than 2bhp/50cc)</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
         <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew">
<br>
<label for="gvw">Gross Vehicle Weight:</label>
         <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw">
<br>             
<label for="ft">Feet:</label>
         <input type="text" name="ft" id="ft">
```

Comment: let me get this clear please , your inputs are vehicle class , and the weight ( doesnt matter empty or gross ) , then you need to retrieve corresponding pipe based upon these 2 inputs ?

Comment: The drop down is vehicle body  then three text boxes ew,gvw,ft. Depending on the option chosen from the drop down it will decide which text box will be used to calculate weight/ft using my function getWeight. Then it will calculate the correct pipe. Some options though do no need weight/ft and are none so it should know to calculate without needing a weight/ft

Comment: and how can you tell what to use ( ew,gvw,ft) where are these attributes specified in your object props ?

Comment: In my getWeight function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access a stringed variable based on a drop down and text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916069/access-a-stringed-variable-based-on-a-drop-down-and-text-box). Why have you asked an almost identical question around the same time as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go :).  See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wb9z2uuw/11/

I found a few problems in the code.  First - in your dataset - every object must have the two properties `minWeight` and `maxWeight`.  If the `minWeight` and `maxWeight` property don't matter for a specific vehicle, then set them to 0 and Number.MAX_VALUE respectively.  This ensures that the function that retrieves the pipe value works correctly.  For example:

```
"PT1": [{
    vehicleClass: "none",
    minWeight: 0,
    maxWeight: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    pipe: [6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 12.50, 12.50, 12.50, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 25.00, 31.25, 31.25, 31.25, 1, 36.60, 25.00, 2, 2, 0, 76]
}],
```

Second - in the `eventHandler()` function, the variables were being declared outside of the function, so the values were remaining as they were the first time the function ran, which is why the code wasn't working at all.

*Original:*

```
var weight = getWeight(vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value);
var vehiclebody = document.getElementById("vehiclebody");
var eventHandler = function () {
    if (weight !== "" && vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value != "") {
        for (var i in Automobiles) {
            if (i === vehiclebody.options[vehiclebody.selectedIndex].value) {
                for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                    if (weight >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && weight < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                        alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*New:*

```
var eventHandler = function () {
    var weight = getWeight();
    var vehiclebody = $("#vehiclebody").val();
    if (weight !== "" && vehiclebody != "") {
        for (var i in Automobiles) {
            if (i === vehiclebody) {
                for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                    if (weight >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && weight < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                        alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Also - just to help me out a little understanding which value I was supposed to enter, I added in some dynamic hiding and showing of the text boxes in the `getWeight()` function, you can remove these if you want

```
if (vehicle == '2D' || vehicle == '3D' || vehicle == '4D' || vehicle == '5D' || vehicle == 'CV' || vehicle == 'UT' || vehicle == 'SW' || vehicle == 'TL1' || vehicle == 'TL2' || vehicle == 'PK' || vehicle == 'VN1' || vehicle == 'VN3' || vehicle == 'CA2' || vehicle == 'PC' || vehicle == 'MH') {
    $("#gvw, label[for='gvw'], #ft, label[for='ft']").val("").hide();
    $("#ew, label[for='ew']").show();
    weight = $('#ew').val();  //WEIGHT BASED ON EW
}
```

Here's the complete code (minus the dataset, StackOverflow has a 30,000 character limit on answers):

**HTML:**

```
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody">
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="2D">2-Door Coupe</option>
    <option value="3D">3-Door Hatchback</option>
    <option value="4D">4-Door Sedan</option>
    <option value="5D">5-Door Hatchback</option>
    <option value="CV">Convertible</option>
    <option value="UT">Sport Utility Vehicle</option>
    <option value="SW">Station Wagon</option>
    <option value="TL1">Trailers (utility or boat) under 500 lbs</option>
    <option value="TL2">Trailers (utility or boat) over 500 lbs</option>
    <option value="PK">Truck (Equal to or Less than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="TK1">Truck (More than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="TK2">Agricultural Truck</option>
    <option value="TK3">Agricultural Goat</option>
    <option value="TK4">Forestry Truck</option>
    <option value="TK5">Wrecker Truck</option>
    <option value="VN1">Van-Cargo (Equal to or Less than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="VN2">Van-Cargo (More than 5000 lbs)</option>
    <option value="VN3">Van-Passenger</option>
    <option value="CA1">Camper (folding wall or popup)</option>
    <option value="CA2">Chassis Mount Camper (unit affixed to truck chassis)</option>
    <option value="HS1">Mobile Home Outside Mobile Home Park(rental property)</option>
    <option value="HS2">Mobile Home Inside Mobile Home Park(rental property)</option>
    <option value="HS3">Mobile Home (real property)</option>
    <option value="PC">Motor Coach (3 axles)</option>
    <option value="MH">Motor Home (2 axles)</option>
    <option value="PT1">Park Model (rental property)</option>
    <option value="PT2">Park Model (real property)</option>
    <option value="TV1">Travel Trailer</option>
    <option value="TV2">Travel Trailer (real property)</option>
    <option value="MC1">Motorcycle (More than 2bhp or 50cc)</option>
    <option value="MC2">Motorscooter (Equal to/Less than 2bhp/50cc)</option>
    <option value="MP">Moped (Equal to/Less than 2bhp/50cc)</option>
</select>

<label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
<input type="text" name="ew" id="ew" />

<label for="gvw">Gross Vehicle Weight:</label>
<input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" />

<label for="ft">Feet:</label>
<input type="text" name="ft" id="ft" />
```

**Dataset:**

**I had to remove the dataset due to StackOverflow's 30,000 character limit for an answer -- See the fiddle for complete dataset**

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#ew, label[for='ew'], #gvw, label[for='gvw'], #ft, label[for='ft']").hide();
function getWeight() {
    var weight = 0;
    var vehicle = $("#vehiclebody").val();
    if (vehicle == '2D' || vehicle == '3D' || vehicle == '4D' || vehicle == '5D' || vehicle == 'CV' || vehicle == 'UT' || vehicle == 'SW' || vehicle == 'TL1' || vehicle == 'TL2' || vehicle == 'PK' || vehicle == 'VN1' || vehicle == 'VN3' || vehicle == 'CA2' || vehicle == 'PC' || vehicle == 'MH') {
        $("#gvw, label[for='gvw'], #ft, label[for='ft']").val("").hide();
        $("#ew, label[for='ew']").show();
        weight = $('#ew').val();  //WEIGHT BASED ON EW
    }
    else if (vehicle == 'TK1' || vehicle == 'TK2' || vehicle == 'TK3' || vehicle == 'TK4' || vehicle == 'TK5' || vehicle == 'VN2') {
        $("#ew, label[for='ew'], #ft, label[for='ft']").val("").hide();
        $("#gvw, label[for='gvw']").show();
        weight = $('#gvw').val(); //WEIGHT BASED ON GVW 
    }
    else if (vehicle == 'HS1' || vehicle == 'HS2' || vehicle == 'TV1' || vehicle == 'TV2') {
        $("#ew, label[for='ew'], #gvw, label[for='gvw']").val("").hide();
        $("#ft, label[for='ft']").show();
        weight = $('#ft').val(); //WEIGHT BASED ON FT 
    }
    else {
        $("#ew, label[for='ew'], #gvw, label[for='gvw'], #ft, label[for='ft']").val("").hide();
        weight = 0; //CA1, HS3, PT1, PT2, MC1, MC2, MP
    }
    return weight;
}
var eventHandler = function () {
    var weight = getWeight();
    var vehiclebody = $("#vehiclebody").val();
    if (weight !== "" && vehiclebody != "") {
        for (var i in Automobiles) {
            if (i === vehiclebody) {
                for (var a = 0; a < Automobiles[i].length; a++) {
                    if (weight >= Automobiles[i][a].minWeight && weight < Automobiles[i][a].maxWeight) {
                        alert(Automobiles[i][a].pipe);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
$("#ew, #gvw, #ft, #vehiclebody").change(function () { eventHandler() });
```

Comment: sure, what do u need?

Comment: No Problem at all, I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Would you like me to test your skills even deeper? Hahaha

Comment: lol.  sure, I'm a JavaScript ninja!  I can take anything you can throw at me.

Comment: alright so I need to combine this with my fee calculator pipes 1 - 15 will be based on the birth month they chose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64951/discussion-between-vicki-and-howard-renollet).